# Include date module in custom module

Tags: datetime

I have а custom module that will show some reports. It will have two textfields, so when a user clicks one of the fields "starting date" and "end date" a calendar will popup and will able to select the dates. After selecting the dates, it will show the table with the results.

I've been using "Date" module with content type/fields, but I've never done in a custom module.

If these are the two fields:

```
<?php

$content['starting_date'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Starting date',
);

$content['end_date'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'End date',
);

?>
```

How can I show the popup calendar when a user clicks on some of the textfields and show the results?

I'm using Drupal 7.

EDIT: I'm marking Clive's answer, but the date_popup works only on forms, not custom fields.

Comment: Why do you need a custom module for this? Isn't content type with fields doing the job?

Comment: The page has a custom access callback, connects with a web service and all the results are gathering from there .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the date popup module installed and enabled:

```
$form['starting_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => 'Starting date',
  '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
  '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
);
```

Comment: I've just tried that. It doesn't show the popup. The date module and date_popup is already instaled. When I revert to "#type" => 'textfield' it's showing the textfield with no problems.

Comment: I just tried it too (copy and pasted) into a normal form, works perfectly for me

Comment: Ok, I've tried on a form too. Yes, it's working, but on my custom page callback that doesn't use form, I cannot make the date_popup appear.

Comment: The date popup is a form element, so it won't work outside of a form. If you don't want to use a form you'll need to implement a custom JS solution, the date module won't be able to help you unfortunately

Comment: +1 from me and I've edited my thread. So I guess I have to find how to implement custom JS for that. Too bad the date module wont help.

Comment: It should be simple enough to simulate with `date_popup_add()` (to add the libraries) and a simple JS script: `(function($) { $(function() { $('#datepicker').datepicker(); }); })(jQuery);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12837/discussion-between-user2519032-and-clive)